# UIActivityIndicatorView is not display at the right time

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview, uiviewanimation

I'm making a form that allows the user to enter datas in my IOS application. This form allows the user to enter a lot of repetive datas. So, sometimes, the process takes time and I would like to display a UIActivityIndicatorView during this process.

Unfortunalty the spinner appears only one second or less at the end of the process, not at the beginning as expected.

There is some code :

```
- (void) manageSpinner{
    spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [spinner setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2.0, self.view.bounds.size.height/2.0)]; // I do this becau I'm in landscape mode
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dark_gradiant.jpg"];
    [imageView setImage:image];
    [imageView addSubview:spinner];
    [self.tableView addSubview:imageView];
    [spinner startAnimating];
}


//On click save by the user
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender{

    //Collect information from the form

    myObject.name = nameTF.text;

    [...]

    if(informations OK[...]){        
        //Manage spinner
        [self manageSpinner];

        //Add : this is the long process
        for (int i=0; i<nbRepeatChooseByUser; i++) {
            [myObject register];
        }

        //Call the delegate that will dismiss the form
        [self.delegate theSaveButtonOnTheAddMyObjectTVCWasTapped:self];
    }
}
```

The spinner is called before the adding method but it seems to be set up after the process.

Thank you,

Alexandre

Comment: Regardless of the actual question, this seems to be a very bad UI-design decision. Activity indicators are meant to show that the device is working, not you.

Comment: You are probably right. It is the first time I try to implement activity indicators. Do you have any clue to indicate me how to use it the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The activity indicator is running on the same thread as your long process thus the animation does not start as soon as you want. Try to run your long process in the background thread.

```
if(informations OK[...]){        
    //Manage spinner
    [self manageSpinner];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        // Do your background process here
        //Add : this is the long process
        for (int i=0; i<nbRepeatChooseByUser; i++) {
            [myObject register];
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //This section will be called after your long process has been completed.

            //Call the delegate that will dismiss the form
            [self.delegate theSaveButtonOnTheAddMyObjectTVCWasTapped:self];
        });

    });

}
```

Comment: @Alexandre If you are happy with the answer, you should accept the solution. Click on the "white" tick (check mark) beside this answer. Cheers. Vito

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the TableView is using up the mainThread and at the same time you want the spinner to perform.in such a case the compiler will queue the actions.Hence the spinner animation occurs abruptly..

To synchronize the actions make the spinner animate in background thread..

Perform the following options to start and stop the spinner

start :   `[spinner performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startAnimating) withObject:self];`
 stop :   `[spinner performSelectorInBackground:@selector(stopAnimating) withObject:self];`

Answer (score 0):

The Activity indicator is blocked by the operation that was performed after it in the main thread.
So change the operation to back ground thread like like:

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue;
backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("registerqueue", NULL); 
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^(void) {
        for (int i=0; i<nbRepeatChooseByUser; i++)
        {
            [myObject register];
        }
    });
```

Don't forget to import

```
#import <dispatch/dispatch.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a nice MIT library to manage UISpinner : https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD